# How to make an exe file to run in all systems which don't having JVM?

Tags: java

I recently developed an desktop application using java....i made .exe file using launch4j...
It gets executed on machines that have only JVM...
Propose me a way to make it executable on machines that don't have JVM

Comment: You can configure launch4j to include a jre.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Excelsior JET](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jet.html) to compile Java into a native executable file on Windows that doesn't depend on the JRE.

Another solution could be [GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/)

Comment: GCJ development seems to be dead. No GUI (awt/swing support) and no updates since 2009

Answer (score 0):

I use [WinRun4J](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/)

You just copy the entire JVM to your program's directory and create an .ini file with contents similar to these:

`main.class=com.program.Main
working.directory=.
classpath.1=.\lib\*.jar
vm.location=.\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll`

where `jre7` is the directory with copied JRE.

Be aware that you need to check if you abide by JRE's licence.